# Can I use an older DLL than the one in the GAC?

Tags: .net, dll

I have a DLL registered in the GAC. I want to use an older version of the DLL in my project.
I have a copy of the older DLL in my project and set a reference to it but I still get the DLL from the GAC.

The DLLs have different file and product versions, but the same public key token.

Is it possible to load the local/old DLL instead of the newer in the GAC?

I've tried the following in my app.config, but no luck.

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="amqmdnet"
        publicKeyToken="dd3cb1c9aae9ec97"
        culture="neutral" />
      <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in application, 
      publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.5.0.4" newVersion="7.0.1.6" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Yes.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot.

Comment: If you have a csproj (or a vbproj), try editing the xml directly and make sure the full strong name is specified and SpecificVersion tag for that reference is there and set to true.